# Is there any Eclipse plug-in for developing Google Chrome extensions?

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-extension

I started to developing a Google Chrome extensions, 
Until now I used Gedit editor.

I wonder whether there's an Eclipse plug-in for developing Google Chrome extensions?

Comment: Technically, I think this question is off-topic (favorite library or off-site resource), though I've always though these sorts of question good and appropriate.